# Instanceof self

Tags: javascript, requirejs

```
// util/model.js

define(['util/class'], function(classCtor) {
    return classCtor.create({
        set: function(key, value) {
            // this doesn't work, because self is pointing to window
            if (value instanceof self) {
                // do Something
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This should be the base class of all my entitys. Because my modules are written in RequireJS style, i'm able to use the following workaround:

```
if (value instanceof require('util/model'))
```

This works fine, but now my code is coupled to the ModuleName. Any suggestions how to avoid this coupling? 
By the way: I use the prototype-based helper from [Steffen Rusitschka](http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2008/12/javascript-inheritance-via-prototypes-and-closures) to build my classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a variable for your anonymous class:

```
define(['util/class'], function(classCtor) {
    var self = classCtor.create({
        set: function(key, value) {
            // self is the class now:
            if (value instanceof self) {
                // do Something
            }
        }
    });
    return self;
});
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much! I was on the right way but already such insane that i compared it with === instead of instanceof... oops :)